# could not load file or assembly HtmAgilityPack verion 1.4.6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Ok, i have tried EVERYTHING mentioned on the internet. I have made most of my project in VS 2013 Express for Web. Since it doesn't support Crystal Reports, i reverted to VS2012 Ultimate. It opened the solution just fine and is working as well. The trouble i am having is when i try to add report, it goes past the Naming part, when it is about to load the report page it gives me the following error: [ErrorLink](http://prntscr.com/69a4l3). 
My Toolkit was working fine on VS2013. 
Toolkit version: 7.1213
AjaxMin: 4.97
HtmlAglilityPack: 1.4.9

I am giving my web.config file here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SMC-20141224085758.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SMC-20141224085758;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="masterConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=sana\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SMCConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=sana\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SMC;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"></add>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.4" newVersion="2.1.0.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly> 
 <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />  
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.4.5.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly> 
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I rebuilt the solution, cleaned it. I don't know what else to do. Any kind of help will be deeply appreciated.

**Error Message:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.6.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: A missing assembly reference or assembly version conflict could result for that,, IMO it's due to a version conflict.

Comment: how should i fix that?

Comment: Have you tried add the reference within the solution itself? Right click references, add reference, browse to assembly, select it, click okay/apply. Also, I could be wrong but shouldn't the PublicToken be unique even if it's the a different version of the same assembly?

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: @CalebB i am going to try out your suggestion, hold on please

Comment: May be <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />

Comment: @CalebB wait, what exactly am i looking for here?

Comment: @KcDoD it's already added there buddy.

Comment: do you need both assembly references for agility pack ?? I think new version is enough..

Comment: i removed the old version one, and the one with newer version was already there.

Comment: In you `<assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a"...` The AssemblyIdentity.PublicKeyToken property is the same on version 1.4.6.0 and 1.4.9.0, this property is the last 8 bytes of the SHA-1 hash of the public key under which the assembly is signed. My thoughts are that when the assembly is referenced in your config file the two assemblies are ambiguous. Do you need both assemblies for compatibility with older machines or is it possible to remove the older of the two assemblies?

Comment: @CalebB now that's what I'm talking.. Do you need both ? And version which doesn't exist ?

Comment: well i have removed `<assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />  
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.4.5.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0" />`
and `<assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />` is still there

Comment: @Sana Qureshi keep the new version, only remove the older version with 1.4.6.0

Comment: Also make sure to rebuild your solution after making an adjustment to the config file. @KcDoD and Sana Qureshi, on a side note we may want to move this to a chat session if it goes more extensive than this, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: alright, i'll try rebuilding it. thanks. hold on

Comment: still the same. -curses-

Comment: At what point does the error occur? Is there a way you can set a break point in the method that loads the report and step through it to get a better idea of what specifically is throwing the exception?

Comment: @mason The "ErrorLink" hyperlink In the question is the error message. Using this instead of typing it our provides a visual aid in addition to the message itself. This is not neglecting the error message but stating it in a different format.

Comment: @mason I understand, that is a good point I did not think of. I made an edit suggestion that clarifies the op's error message within the question itself.

Comment: it gives error after i enter the name for report, as soon as the report is almost loaded, the error occurs @CalebB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71681/discussion-between-calebb-and-sana-qureshi).

Comment: i'm risking looking like the biggest fool in the village, but after breaking my head over the issue, i noticed that i didn't import the HtmlAgliltyPack.dll to the target location, so in the visual studio environment everything worked, but on the server i got the above message. once i have put the dll next to the exe on the server, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i did alot of searching and thanks to @Caleb and other person for being with me through it all. i uninstalled and reinstalled the different version of CR. It brought up some COM error about some object model lib. I removed the reference and tada.. it's working fine now.
And DO NOT forget to do this:

`When using ADO.NET with the Microsoft .NET Framework
4.0 (and above), the following setting must be added to the application’s configuration file:

```
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>`
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error is with the version of assembly.

You specify that you work with follow :

> HtmlAglilityPack: 1.4.9.0

In your code you have following

```
 <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />  
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.4.5.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0" />
```

I believe it shouldn't be there since you are using the newer version 1.4.9.0 and you already have that reference. (Which I miss to note on my first try to answer)

```
  <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I thought the csproj was updated automatically when upgrading nuget packages?

Answer (score 1):

Try this !!

1) Just right click on your Solution 
[image]

2) Search For AjaxControlToolkit online

3) click on install

4) Restart Visual Studio

5)Build & Run

All The Best

Answer (score 0):

1. This problem can be arise due to the mismatch of the following dlls included in the project.Either any of the dll/package is missing or not the correct version, so either install or update that package:

AjaxControlToolkit
AjaxMin
HtmlAgilityPack

Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manger Console

PM> install-package [name of the package with correct version]

Example: PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.4.6

Answer (score 0):

> Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.6.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I tried clearing all the temporary files from Temp  folder. Just type `%Temp%` and delete all the files from that folder. 

Then cheers my problem was solved.

**Note: I tried the following but did not worked:

(i) Rebuilding, restarting, cleaning the solution + projects.

(ii) Referencing with its dll again.

(iii) clearing the data from the path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

(iv) Downloading the missing packages.**